# Reflection of floor materials

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor, lighting

I'm a Blender newbie, following a tutorial. The floor is dull, showing no glossy contrast like in the tutorial (shown in the lower part in the picture). Even if I raise the power of the environment texture to 17 as instructed, the floor is just all lighter, not having the contrast of shadow and light.

Anyone can help me with this? thanks a ton in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What i can see that the problem is in the material of the floor. can i now What is the material using in the floor ? And the light source ?

Comment: a link to the tutorial you are following would be very useful.

Comment: Please add an image of the nodes used for the floor material

Answer (score 2):

You need a [Glossy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/glossy.html) shader for this.

- Open a node editor.
- Go to the material tab (in the first set, looks like a ball), and then make sure you're in the object tab (in the second set, looks like a cube).
- Select (right-click) the Diffuse BSDF node.
- Press Shift+S and switch its type to a Glossy BSDF.

This will give you reflections. You can play with the reflection color and roughness until it looks right.

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/introduction.html) for more information on Cycles materials.

Comment: as a general rule you should never change the color of a glossy shader if your material is a non metal (dielectric) material. You should instead mix is with a diffuse shader

Answer (score -1):

you can try adding either a glossy bsdf to the material in the node editor or an aisotropic shader (although you might have to tweak it cuz its meant more for metals)